# How do you choose between using a Jumbotron or Carousel?

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap

I'm developing my first ever responsive website. This website will be a one-page website for one of my software products. I'm having a hard time trying to decide whether to use a jumbotron or a carousel.

What goes into your decisions when choosing between using a jumbotron or carousel?
What are the benefits of using a jumbotron instead of a carousel?
What are the benefits of using a carousel over a jumbotron?

Comment: Michael, while I can see the UX relation, I think you'll need to re-write your question so it doesn't get voted down or closed for being off topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been several studies to the effectiveness of carousels. The effectiveness differs slightly per type of website, but the click-through-rate is horribly low on all accounts. Some as low as 1%.

So chances are big visitors will miss information.

And like Poyi said, carousel also have the nasty habit of changing content while visitors are reading.

So why do they exist? Marketeers and lack of screen estate (especially on mobile screens).

In my opinion, carousels only work with images. Like different images of a product in a webshop or on the portfolio of a photographer.

If you do want to use a carousel, there are some ways of making them as effective as possible. First, don't put a lot of content in it. Based on [Miller's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two) that will be around 7. But in my opinion, less is even better since Miller's Law is not based on carousels with non-visible content.
The second tip is to display thumbnails showing the content of the carousel. You might have seen them. The carousels with their content shown as a list beside them.

See what works for you.

Some links:
http://erikrunyon.com/2013/07/carousel-interaction-stats/
http://erikrunyon.com/2013/01/carousel-stats/

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/
http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Comment: Will you please include the links (or a couple of them) to the studies you refer to that measure the effectiveness of carousels. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelRiley-AKAGunny added them to the post

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by jumbotron you mean a static section with image or text overlay on top.

A jumbotron may feel less intrusive for some users compare to a carousel because it doesn't change content while the user is reading. On the other hand, you cannot put as much content within the same real estate within a jumbotron section due to the lack of slides/layers.

In my opinion, the decision is mainly based on the type of content as well as the amount of content you like to display. For instance, if you want to feature a series of large images in a given space then carousel may be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather debatable topic. i've seen way too many times where marketing wants (or doesn't want to let go of) the carousel simply because it can show many campaigns at the same time. That's the advantage of using Carousels. in that sense jumbotrons are limited but you can make the user focus more.